# What's the difference between "Hola, ¿cómo te llamas usted?" and "Hola, ¿cuál es to nombre?" and when would I use one or the other?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, saludos

I'm taking a Spanish course and can't figure out when I am supposed to use these:

- ¿Cómo te llamas?
- ¿Cuál es tu nombre?

Does it have to do with who I am referring to?

Comment: I think the tag might be the wrong one for the situation - I'm new to spanish y no hablo mucho espanol.

Comment: Note in your title you are mixing two forms for you: the formal and the informal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar cualquiera de las dos frases. Significan lo mismo. La respuesta puede ser de cualquier forma también, no deben corresponder necesariamente:

- ¿Cómo te llamas? Mi nombre es Pablo.
- ¿Cuál es tu nombre? Me llamo Jorge.

Como quieras decirlo.

Ahora, si usas usted, debes decir:

- ¿Cómo se llama usted?, o
- ¿Cuál es su nombre?

Answer (score 2):

Es lo mismo; la diferencia es el nivel de formalidad.

Ejemplo:
Cuando conoces a un nuevo amigo le dices, Hola ¿cómo te llamas?
Cuando vas a conocer a tu suegro le dices, Hola ¿cuál es su nombre?

Answer (score 1):

Well, in both sentences are minor errors:

- “Hola, como te llama usted?”   should be “Hola, como **se** llama usted?”
- “Hola, cual es to nombre?”      should be “Hola, cual es **tu** nombre?”

(I guest that the second one was a typo)

In the first sentence you are mixing the formal and informal way. If you want to maintain it formal, use the correction that I gave you. If you want to keep it informal, remove "usted".

- “Hola, como te llamas?   (Works for all genders but only in singular)

The second phrase is another way to ask for the name informally.

In summary:

**Informal.**

- “Hola, como te llamas?"
- “Hola, cual es tu nombre?”

**Formal.**

- “Hola, como se llama usted?”
- “Hola, cual es su nombre?”

Remember, whatever you use, people are going to understand what do you mean, it just might sound a little strange.

Comment: como se llamas usted is definitely incorrect throughout your answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just cut and paste and modified the only part that I thought was wrong. Thanks.